# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp.user'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

at urls.py, I want to import webapp/user/views.py/ConfirmEmailView.

so write code like this > from webapp.user.views import ConfirmEmailView

and here is my Directory Structure..
[image]

but when I run this, error arises..

```
daesin_back-django-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "manage.py", line 24, in <module>
daesin_back-django-1  |     main()
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "manage.py", line 19, in main
daesin_back-django-1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
daesin_back-django-1  |     utility.execute()
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
daesin_back-django-1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
daesin_back-django-1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 443, in execute
daesin_back-django-1  |     self.check()
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
daesin_back-django-1  |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
daesin_back-django-1  |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
daesin_back-django-1  |     return check_resolver(resolver)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
daesin_back-django-1  |     return check_method()
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
daesin_back-django-1  |     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
daesin_back-django-1  |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
daesin_back-django-1  |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
daesin_back-django-1  |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
daesin_back-django-1  |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
daesin_back-django-1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
daesin_back-django-1  |   File "/srv/docker-server/webapp/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
daesin_back-django-1  |     from webapp.user.views import ConfirmEmailView
daesin_back-django-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp.user'
```

I don't know why it cannot find webapp.user!!!

even pycharm's autocomplete is work nomally.

please help me if you know the reason......

++add (this is my folder structure)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your root package directory is not the webapp package. Your root package is determined by the location of manage.py. So you have to import your ConfirmEmailView by calling: `from user.views import ConfirmEmailView`.

You will probably need to put all django apps into a dedicated package like "apps" if you want to prevent package name conflict with external libs.